# Simple sine calculator doesn't return the right values

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

The math.sine module seem to return wrong values. Where did I made a mistake ?

```py
import math

A = float(input("Insert a number you want the sine of"))

B = math.sin(math.radians(A))
print("sin of %.2f is %.6f" % (A, B))
```

The result for typing 45 is 0.707 instead of 0.85

I was just getting back into Python. I can't see the error.

Comment: But `sin(45°)` *is* `1/Sqrt[2]==0.707` while `sin(45)==0.85`.

Comment: The sin of 45 degrees is  0.707, which is what your program gives you. You are asking the user to introduce an angle in degrees.

Comment: sin(45 radians) is `0.85`...Not degrees

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, there is difference between `degrees` and `radians`. You probably confused them with each other.

Calculate with radians:

```py
import math

A = float(input("Insert a number you want the sine of"))

B = math.sin(math.radians(A))
print("sin of %.2f is %.6f" % (A, B))
```

Calculate with degrees:

```py
import math

A = float(input("Insert a number you want the sine of"))

B = math.sin(math.degrees(A))
print("sin of %.2f is %.6f" % (A, B))
```